# JWT expired, unexpected response in nodejs API

Tags: node.js, api, authentication, routes, jwt

i have a problem when i try to use a private api in my node.js server, This is the process that i am following

1. SignUp (if the user doesn't have an account) or logIn (already have an account).
2. It generates the token and i pass it in the header `res.header('access_token': token)`
3. I copy this token and paste it in my private api in the header section (i'm using postman to test it for now) in order to verify if the user is logged in.
4. In my route, i use a middleware to turn it private, validating if the user can use the resource `jwt.verify(authorization[1], process.env.SEED_AUTH)` (SEED_AUTH is my token secret stored in my server)

Here is when i have the error, the middleware is failling to verify the user and throw me this error `jwt expired`

**This is my route**

```
const UsersController = require('../controllers/users.controller')
const AuthorizationMiddleware = require('../middlewares/authorization.middleware')

exports.routesConfig = (app) => {

  app.post('/api/users',[
    AuthorizationMiddleware.verifyValidJWT
  ], UsersController.insert)
}
```

**This is my middleware**

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')
require('../config/env.config')

exports.verifyValidJWT = (req, res, next) => {
  if (req.headers['access-token']) {
    try {
      let authorization = req.headers['access-token'].split(' ');
      if (authorization[0] !== 'Bearer') {
        return res.status(401).json({
          ok: false,
          err: "Unauthorized, Need a valid token"
        });
      } else {
        console.log(authorization[1]);
        req.jwt = jwt.verify(authorization[1], process.env.SEED_AUTH);
        return next();
      }
    } catch (error) {
      return res.status(403).json({
        ok: false,
        err: "Forbidden, need a valid token -> " + error.message
      });
    }
  } else {
    return res.status(401).json({
      ok: false,
      err: "Need to recieve a valid token"
    });
  }
}
```

**And finally the API  UsersController.insert**

What i'm trying to do with this api is to create a new user.

**For a better understanding this is my LOGIN API**

```
const User = require('../models/users.model')
const { signUpValidation, logInValidation } = require('../middlewares/auth.validation.data')
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt')
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')

exports.logIn = async (req, res) => {

  let body = req.body;

  //Validation
  const { error } = logInValidation(body)
 
  if (error) {
    return res.status(400).json({
      ok: false,
      err: error.details[0].message
    })
  }

  //Check if the email already exists in the database
  const user = await User.findOne({ email: body.email })
  if (!user) {
    return res.status(400).json({
      ok: false,
      err: "Invalid Email or password!"
    })
  }

  const validPass = await bcrypt.compareSync(body.password, user.password)
  if (!validPass) {
    return res.status(400).json({
      ok: false,
      err: "Invalid Email or password!"
    })
  }
  
  const token = jwt.sign(
    {
      _id: user._id,
      email: user.email
    },
    process.env.SEED_AUTH,
    {
      expiresIn: process.env.TOKEN_EXPIRY
    }
  )
  
  res.header('access-token', token).json({
    ok: true,
    user: {
      id: user._id,
      email: user.email
    }
  });
}
```

**SignUp and LogIn validation**
I use these middleware to verify if it is a valid email, and the name with a minimum number of letters...

My `process.env.TOKEN_EXPIRY` is set to `300` (i understand that, it is in seconds), i've tried with bigger number though

(The API works without the middleware).

What would be the problem that i am not seeing. Thanks for your help.

Comment: could you add the token generation code (the .sign()). Also it is suggested to use an SSL key pair instead of a plaintext password

Comment: yes i will add it, i've hashed the password with bcrypt module, before store the user in the database

Comment: @Simon it's not the users password that's the problem, it's the jwt secret key. There are 2 ways to sign tokens: using pre shared keys (PSKs) aka secrets, which you have here, or you could use key pairs by signing with a private key and verifying with public keys. This is normally the preferred method.

Comment: Hi thanks for your response, i didn't know abut the second one i think that i will investigate about it because i don't understand how to implement it already. So is that my error? because  i've done a couple of tutorials with this same pattern and it works for them. i have updated the question with my login logic for a better understanding

Comment: Maybe use iat and exp fields instead of expiresIn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

process.env variables are as string and not as a number. According to the [jsonwebtoken](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken) documentation, string is considered as milliseconds by default and number is counted as seconds by default. So change TOKEN_EXPIRY to 300000 from 300

Comment: Thanks for your comment, it was really helpful.

I was using the environment variable `TOKEN_EXPIRY` as a string.

I changed the time to 300000 and it works properly.

Thanks for your help i was implementing bad the `TOKEN_EXPIRY`.